# Retrieving listview datas issue on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms.listview

To be quick, I have a listview with datas that I get from rest API and an entry, works fine, displays well. The user is supposed to type in the entry.
On the bottom of this listview, I have a button "accept", and with this button, im supposed to retrieve evevry object of the listview.

code is something like this :

xaml:

```
<ListView>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                            <Label Text="{Binding label}" />

                            <Entry />

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                    <Button Text="ACCEPT" Clicked="acceptClicked" />
            </ListView.Footer>
     </ListView>
```

I've been searching but I can't find anything or maybe im not searching the right way.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Done. the .cs code isn't useful to share here, there's just the API request. Its not the exact same code bcause i don't think im allowed to share it.

Comment: you need to Bind the entry's value to a property in your model, then when the button is clicked you can simply use the List's datasource to get the modified values

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, if you want to get ListView data, you can bind then Entry's text to one property in Model, implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, you can take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

                            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Button Clicked="acceptClicked" Text="ACCEPT" />
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<person3> persons { get; set; }
    public Page5 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<person3>()
        {
            new person3(){FirstName="Cherry",LastName=""},
            new person3(){FirstName="Barry",LastName=""},
            new person3(){FirstName="Wendy",LastName=""},
            new person3(){FirstName="Yong",LastName=""},
            new person3(){FirstName="Jessie",LastName=""},
            new person3(){FirstName="Leo",LastName=""},
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void acceptClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach(person3 p in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.LastName);
        }
    }
}

public class person3:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");

        }
    }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set
        {
            _LastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModelBase class, implement INotifyPropertyChanged, ListView Itemsource will update when you change Entry text.

```
public class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```